# Using CMake with CPP and ASM on Windows template doesn't work

Tags: c++, assembly, cmake

https://github.com/Ybalrid/cmake-cpp-nasm this project doesn't compile with errors:

`[build] cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _asm_foo referenced in function _main [C:\Users\[username]\Downloads\cmake-cpp-nasm-master\build\cmake-cpp-nasm.vcxproj] [build]     Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match: [build]       asm_foo`

How do I get rid of these errors?

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, without any actual code to look at, there's no way we can answer this.

Comment: @Spencer But there is actual code. I literally linked the repo I downloaded the code from.

Comment: The code needs to actually be in the question. Follow the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Why? I don't see that written there.

Comment: Look in the "Complete" section.  _"Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included in the question itself"_ .... _"Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then format it as code."_

Comment: Well, there was a lot of excess code. My question pointed out a problem with the template, so I linked the repo (to show that I didn't modify it). Also, there was a lot of unrelated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to fix this by adding a space:

Old:

```
if(WIN32)
    string(APPEND CMAKE_ASM_NASM_FLAGS "-dWIN32=1")
endif(WIN32)
```

New:

```
if(WIN32)
    string(APPEND CMAKE_ASM_NASM_FLAGS " -dWIN32=1")
endif(WIN32)
```

Comment: Ah, you might be missing a space there, I think, since you are appending to a string. Have you tried leaving this in and adding a space right after the opening quote?

Comment: Yes, you're right, lol. That works too!